# counting the number of permutations of n number have k places that decrease

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, recursion

The n size list is a list of integer numbers {1,2,3,..., n}.

I will use examples to show "have k places that decrease":

{4,3,1,2} where n=4, k=2. cause 4>3,3>1

{4,1,2,3} where n=4, k=1.cause 4>1

{1,5,4,2,3} where n=5, k=2. cause 5>4,4>2

The default order of the list is increasing.
First I started from k=1, here it means only one pair of numbers is decrease. From 1 to n, I take one numbers outside, and have a (n-1) list left, then I insert the chosen number back to the (n-1) list, and I have(n-1) position to insert it. Now we have n*(n-1) permutation, but for the numbers that are connected with each other, like 1 and 2, 2 and 3, they have repeated patterns which is (n-1), so we need to delete them (but I can not clearly tell the repeated pattern, I used some examples to figure it out, and not sure whether it is correct). so the number of permutation for k=1 is n*(n-1)-(n-1)=(n-1)^2

When k=2, things kindly like out of my control, I am so lost. Don't know how to connected this one to the previous one, I hope I can write in a recursive way or get a close-form for the numbers.

Hope I can have some hints here~~

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

With  the  OP  asking  for  a   hint  we  can  provide  the  following
recursion. Ask how  we can obtain a permutation with  $k$ decreases by
inserting the value  $n$ into a permutation of the  values from $1$ to
$n-1.$  We could  insert $n$  between one  of the  $k$ decreases  of a
permutation on  $n-1$ with  $k$ decreases, which  keeps the  number of
decreases constant. Or we could add it  at the end of a permutation on
$n-1$ with  $k$ decreases.  Lastly  we could insert  it in one  of the
$(n-1)-(k-1)$ locations where there is no decrease of a permutation on
$n-1$ with $k-1$ decreases, thereby  increasing the count of decreases
by one.  This gives the recurrence

$$X_{n,k} = (k+1) X_{n-1, k} + (n-k) X_{n-1,k-1}.$$

The base cases here are $X_{1,0} =  1, X_{1,k} = 0$ and $X_{n,0} = 1,$
for the sorted permutation. Implementing  this in Maple we find (there
is an enumeration routine as well to check the values for small $n$).

```
with(combinat);

ENUM :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local gf, perm, pos, decr;

    gf := 0;

    perm := firstperm(n);

    while type(perm, `list`) do
        decr := 0;

        for pos to n-1 do
            if perm[pos] > perm[pos+1] then
                decr := decr + 1;
            fi;
        od;

        gf := gf + u^decr;

        perm := nextperm(perm);
    od;

    gf;
end;


A := (n, k) -> coeff(ENUM(n), u, k);

X :=
proc(n, k)
option remember;

    if n=1 then
        if k=0 then return 1 fi;
        return 0;
    fi;

    if k=0 then return 1 fi;

    k*X(n-1, k) + X(n-1,k) + (n-k)*X(n-1, k-1)
end;
```

We thus obtain e.g. for $n=7$ the values

$$1, 120, 1191, 2416, 1191, 120, 1.$$

We  look these  up in  the  OEIS and  find  that we  are dealing  with
Eulerian numbers, [OEIS A008292](https://oeis.org/A008292). Presumably
many readers could have recognized the problem statement without doing
the computation.  Anyway the OEIS entry lists a considerable number of
references and should suffice to start  the reader on whatever type of
investigation they plan to do.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I am not smart enough to understand what u wrote immediately, but it is helpful!

Comment: would u mind speaking more about how u get that recursive formula? Xn,k=(k+1)Xn−1,k+(n−k)Xn−1,k−1. I am not a math major, the left part is kind hard to understand. But I am thinking if I can figure out this part, it will also quiet useful.

Comment: I found Eulerian number. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_number        Thanks so much again for your information!

Comment: Now I totally understand your answer, feel so good!